# group_by and create a sparse matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to convert some data to a sparse matrix. It looks like:

```
       col1 col2        
  [1,] "5"  "LQEMF0072E"
  [2,] "3"  "KKZZY5914F"
  [3,] "4"  "UTDLY0947T"
  [4,] "4"  "QKGTX6135E"
  [5,] "1"  "FVKVY7432D"
  [6,] "1"  "RXDLC3097S"
  [7,] "1"  "OQZKN5913X"
  [8,] "2"  "XNTHW9334J"
  [9,] "5"  "AHFFZ7845R"
```

So I have groups:

```
1 = group1
2 = group2
3 = group3
4 = group4
5 = group5
```

I am trying to create a sparse matrix which will be essentially 100 columns wide (number of observations/words) and 5 rows deep (number of groups).

```
group1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
group2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
group3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
etc.
```

Something like the following from the `rsample` package isn`t working for me.

```
sparsedat <- dat %>%
  group_by(as.numeric(col1)) %>%
  cast_sparse(col2)
```

DATA:

```
names <- c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4")
    col1 <- sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE)

    myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
      a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
      paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
    }
    col2 <- myFun(100)
    col2

    dat <- cbind(col1, col2)
    dat
```

EDIT:

This is my output on my data where "col1" is a character vector - group1, group2 ... group 5:

`Warning message:
In storage.mode(from) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion`

```
[1,] NA 11 . 21 .  . 16 9 3 3 1 . . 1  5 . 2 1 2 . . 3 . 3 2 2 1 13 . . . . . . .
[2,] NA  3 6  . .  .  . . . . . . . .  1 . . . 1 2 . 4 2 . 3 . .  . . . . . . . .
[3,] NA  . . 20 1 12  2 4 1 . . 3 5 .  . 2 1 . . . 2 . . . . . .  . . . . . . . .
[4,] NA  . .  9 .  .  1 1 2 . 2 . . . 27 2 . . . . . 2 . . . . .  . 2 1 1 3 1 3 3

[1,] ......
[2,] ......
[3,] ......
[4,] ......
```

The NAs are produced by feeding a column of characters to the matrix. Do I have to factor them and then re-add the character strings? I want to keep the character strings since they help identify the ID of the rows/groups.

EDIT 2: The following seems to replicate my NA issue:

```
names <- c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4")
col1 <- sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE)

col1 <- paste("group", col1)

myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}
col2 <- myFun(100)
col2


dat <- cbind(col1, col2)
dat

dat_sparse <- dat %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  count(col1, col2) %>%
  spread(col2, n, fill = 0) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  Matrix(., sparse = TRUE)

tail(dat_sparse)
```

Comment: `!is.na(reshape2::dcast(data.frame(dat), col1~col2))` OR `Matrix.utils::dMcast(data.frame(dat), col1~col2)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `count` and `spread`. This results in a `data.frame`, which you can easily convert back to a matrix of 1s and 0s.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
    as_data_frame() %>%
    count(col1, col2) %>%
    spread(col2, n, fill = 0)

#   col1  AAPMN9343Q AKGAW7022W AMUQA3013Z AYQOG3513J BARTE6056J ...
#   <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> ...
# 1 1              0          0          0          0          0 ...
# 2 2              1          0          1          1          0 ...
# 3 3              0          0          0          0          0 ...
# 4 4              0          0          0          0          0 ...
# 5 5              0          1          0          0          1 ...
```

In response to your follow up question, you'll first need to create the matrix without including the first column (this avoids the NA by coercion). Then you can add rownames to this matrix.

```
dat_matrix <- as.matrix(dat[,-1]) # exclude first column of character
rownames(dat_matrix) <- dat %>% pull(col1) # add rownames
sparse_dat_matrix <- Matrix::Matrix(dat_matrix, sparse = TRUE) # make sparse

#         AAWYL0013E ABPGV8707B AEMJZ9793B AQTCL9157H ARBYM6583T
# group 1          .          .          .          1          .
# group 2          .          .          1          .          .
# group 3          .          1          .          .          .
# group 4          .          .          .          .          1
# group 5          1          .          .          .          .
```

Comment: One question: I have instead of 1 - 5 as my groups I have a character string (group1, group2 ... group5). When I apply the following: (on my own data) `sparse <- data %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  count(ID, word) %>%
  spread(word, n, fill = 0) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  Matrix(., sparse = TRUE)` - where ID is the (1:5 numbers here but group1, group2.... group5) and the word is the column of words. I get `NA` values for the `ID`column. Do I need to conver the character string to a factor before I input it into a matrix or can I keep the group names? (I add a small edit to the original post)

Comment: Added a seond edit to make the `col1` a character which more closely replicates my data